# SQL Server stored procedure returning data too slowly

Tags: c#, sql-server, asp.net-mvc, linq

I want to get details from table A with columns `id`, `dept`, `course`, `created_date` and some 35 columns which have foreign key relationship with table B in stored procedure.

Finally, I want to pull the data by checking just the "id" in table A should be available as column "userid" and another column having null or 'NO' in the table "B".

Table B has a total of 220 columns.

By getting data by

Query #1

```
Select * 
from A 
where Exists (select userid from B where charge = 'no') 
  and created_date >= '2015-01-01' 
  and created_date <= '2016-01-01'
```

Query #2

```
Select * 
from A aa  
left join B bb on bb.userid = aa.id 
               and charge = 'no' 
where 
    aa.created_date >= '2015-01-01' 
    and aa.created_date <= '2016-01-01'.
```

Actually the performance is too slow.

Observation:

1. If I executed date with hard-coded value in SQL Server stored procedure, it is returning data very fast by pulling 6000 records belongs to 6 month
2. Same, if I executed with dynamic parameters in same stored procedure, it is returning very slowly (45 seconds taken in Amazon server itself)
3. I tried with entity linq facing same issue.

Also I want to get the data by very fast and efficient way too. I am using an ASP.NET MVC 4 web application and executing stored procedure from service method to get the list of data and to be bind it to grid.

Please help to find it.

Comment: Hmm...super fast with parameters in SSMS but super slow as a stored procedure...sounds like the typical symptoms of parameter sniffing. http://sqlinthewild.co.za/index.php/2007/11/27/parameter-sniffing/

Comment: Can you post your LINQ to Entities query

Comment: do you have index on  created_date  column

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you attempted with Entity, did you do any tricks to speed it up? Like AsNoTracking()? In some cases that can speed up retrieving data a ton. Is there anyway to limit the amount of columns you are pulling back? I would limit the columns and add nickname or shortened column alias to each one. That should help a little.

Comment: By Entity , I am getting the data from table A , For ex : It is around 9000 records , then I am checking in that 9000 ,How many of available in table B with condition charges = "NO".  Then It returns me 5000 rows finally after a minute by giving the option .Any() , .Exists() function

Comment: @LakshmiNarasimhanR  Disable Change tracking

You should disable change tracking if it is not needed. Most importantly, you do not need change tracking when you would just want to retrieve data and updates on the data read aren't needed at all.

Comment: This, this was a very important factor that I needed to learn when first running Entity. If you are only retrieving read-only data always disable tracking. This will increase your throughput significantly.

Comment: Here I am getting now fast because of following : 1.First getting the from only table A by checking just the dates . 2. Then , Passing the list data and Checking the availablity in table B with the condition with Entity with  AsNoTracking(). 3. Also Created Index on table A and B on the needed rows. 4, Then I feel the better (50% more) performance than earlier

Answer (score 0):

This is rife with issues.

1. Do you actually need 220 columns returned?  This makes for more network overhead.
2. As-is, query #1 will return columns from A, but query #2 will return columns from both A and B.  Again, more network overhead.
3. The subquery in query #1 does not compare B.userid with A.userid, which means the EXISTS function always evaluates to 1 if the subquery ever returns any single result.
4. "and charge = 'no'" in query #2 belongs in the WHERE clause, not in the JOIN clause.  This could be throwing the optimizer off.
5. In table A, You need a covering index for every column in the WHERE clause, and an index on userid.
6. This is aesthetic only, but consider using the BETWEEN keyword for the date range.  I'm reading that it's processed the same.

Correct some of these issues and try again.